# Are the supply voltage and differential signals put on the same connector?

Tags: power, dc, connector, differential, circular

I have a circular connector. Assembly card size coming from the mechanical department limits me so I must use the pins of the same circular connector for 28V DC power supply and some differential signal. Are the supply voltage and differential signals put on the same connector? Does it make sense? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Cabling comes in a wide variety anymore.  So it should be possible to find cable with twisted pairs *and* dedicated power wires.  Look at CNC machine cable for instance - those both power the motor(s) and deliver data (and are very rugged, albeit expensive.)

Comment: Every USB connection made since 1996 has had power supply and differential data routed through the same connectors and cable. (And that's by no means the earliest example --- we can probably go back to the dawn of digital communications)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is generally acceptable to put power supply lines and differential signal lines in the same connector.

You may have to use a cable in which each pair of twisted conductors is individually shielded.